# Java script not able to be Registered from the behind code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I created Function which will show message like twitter when adding comments in .net 
every things are ok when call the javascript function from aspx file but when try to register it on the page it not worked ?

the function in vb :

```
 Dim script As String = ""
        script &= "  function ErrorMessage121212(TextClass, Error, MainDiv) { "
        script &= "     MainDiv = '#' + MainDiv;"
        script &= "      $(MainDiv).append(""<div align='center' id='overlaytext' style='margin-top:10px'></div>"");"
        script &= "    $(MainDiv).css('color', 'white');"
        script &= "      $(MainDiv).css('align', 'center');"
        script &= "       $(MainDiv).css('backgroundColor', 'black');"
        script &= "       $(MainDiv).css('display', ""none"");"
        script &= "      $('#overlaytext').html(""<b>"" + Error + ""</b>"");"
        script &= "         if (TextClass == """") {"
        script &= "          }"
        script &= "      else { "
        script &= "     $('#overlaytext').addClass(TextClass);"
        script &= "                 }"
        script &= "    $(MainDiv).fadeIn(1000, function () { $(MainDiv).fadeOut(1000); })"
        script &= "     }"
        script &= " ErrorMessage121212('" & MessageCss & "','" & errormessage & "','" & DivID & "');"
        If Not Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("s1") Then
          Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(_page.GetType(), "s1", script)
        End If
        Return True
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting.

Comment: Try to avoid `$(MainDiv)` It will create a new jQuery instance each time you call. Instead of doing `MainDiv = '#' + MainDiv;`, do this `MainDiv = $('#' + MainDiv);`. And use `MainDiv` as instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code its working fine : -

```
Dim script As String = ""
    script &= "  function ErrorMessage121212(TextClass, Error, MainDiv) { "
    script &= "     MainDiv = '#' + MainDiv;"
    script &= "      $(MainDiv).append(""<div align='center' id='overlaytext' style='margin-top:10px'></div>"");"
    script &= "    $(MainDiv).css('color', 'white');"
    script &= "      $(MainDiv).css('align', 'center');"
    script &= "       $(MainDiv).css('backgroundColor', 'black');"
    script &= "       $(MainDiv).css('display', ""none"");"
    script &= "      $('#overlaytext').html(""<b>"" + Error + ""</b>"");"
    script &= "         if (TextClass == """") {"
    script &= "          }"
    script &= "      else { "
    script &= "     $('#overlaytext').addClass(TextClass);"
    script &= "                 }"
    script &= "    $(MainDiv).fadeIn(1000, function () { $(MainDiv).fadeOut(1000); })"
    script &= "     }"
    script &= " ErrorMessage121212('" & MessageCss & "','" & errormessage & "','" & DivID & "');"
    If Not Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("s1") Then
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(_page, _page.GetType, "s1", script, True)
          End If
    Return True
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(_page, typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('a');", true);
```